# JQuery smooth scroll - can this be simplified?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have some very long pages. In the footer I have an anchor link taking the user back to the header. I would like to be able to use the following CSS (but it does not work in Safari) to make the scroll smooth (slow it down).

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

So I have found some JQuery. I don't understand JQuery and have some questions.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // Add smooth scrolling to all links
    $("a").on('click', function(event) {

      // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
      if (this.hash !== "") {
        // Prevent default anchor click behavior
        event.preventDefault();

        // Store hash
        var hash = this.hash;

        // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
        // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        }, 800, function(){
 
          // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
          window.location.hash = hash;
        });
      } // End if
    });
  });
```

1. Is it possible to make this simpler?

2.I'm not sure I need to add the #top to the URL? All I want the page to do is go back to the top (I'm not using anchor links to navigate to bits of content). But I don't know how to remove this code without breaking the whole thing. I've tried and I don't know what to delete and what to keep.

3. What does this mean "Make sure this.hash has a value". I've ignored it and it seems to work ok.

UPDATE

This is my HTML (obviously with a lot of content between the header and footer)

```
<header id="top">.... </header>

<footer>
<a href="#top"><img class="to-top" src="resources/arrow.svg"></a>
</footer>
```

Comment: i mean, removing the jquery entirely and relying on the css, would be simpler, no?

Comment: The CSS does not work in Safari see post

Comment: That's fine. it's not a necessary feature.

Comment: I need the scroll to be smooth, not immediate. So it is necassery.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you are using JQuery only for this feature, use [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) from JavaScript.

With JQuery, this function is enough:

```js
function elevator(where) {
    var the_id = "#" + where;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop:$(the_id).offset().top
    }, 'slow');
    return false;
}
```

which you can use in html tags like this:

```html
<h1 id="title">Title at the top of the page</h1>
<!-- a lot of space -->
<button onclick="elevator('title')">go up</button>
```

> **NOTE:** The CSS property is not useful with this function.

Now if you want an explanation of your code:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    // Add smooth scrolling to all links
    // i.e. select all links on your page and add en event for each of them
    // event called when there is a click
    $("a").on('click', function(event) {

      // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
      // the hash is the anchor. For example: "website.com/page.html#hash"
      // we must check if there is an hash in the link
      if (this.hash !== "") {
        // Prevent default anchor click behavior
        // i.e. the default behavior of a link
        event.preventDefault();

        // Store hash
        var hash = this.hash;

        // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
        // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        }, 800, function(){
 
          // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
          window.location.hash = hash;
        });
      } // End if
    });
  });
```

Your code is creating the smooth effect for every link automatically.

Comment: I've made and linked to a js file, with the above code. But when I click the anchor link it just immediately scrolls to the top. Am I suppose to edit this code / add in my IDs? I've updated my post with my HTML

Comment: "above code" if you're talking about my function `elevator` it's normal. I added a better explanation of your first code (which should work). I'm sorry if I misled you with my first answer.

Comment: @user2991837 I was not answering the question in my initial response, my bad.

Comment: The code starting "function elevator(where..." doesn't work, the scroll is immediate. Do I have to edit this code / add in my own IDs?

Comment: I checked and it's working, however the problem comes, once again, from my lack of explanations

Comment: Thanks.  So do I need the JQuery starting  "function elevator(where) {... " AND  the HTML code "<button onclick="elevator('title')">go up</button>"??

Comment: Ok, I've added the JQuery and the code in the HTML file and it works in Safari. Brilliant. Thanks